# Splitting a list of numbers into a list of lists of pairs

Tags: list, prolog

Say I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, what I want to do is have an output of `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]`.

This is my current attempt at doing this:

```
perms([X,Y], [X,Y], _).
perms(L, R, N) :-
   N > 1,
   N1 is N/2,
   split(L, X1, X2),
   perms(X1, R1, N1),
   perms(X2, R2, N1),
   append([R1], [R2], R).

split(L, R1, R2) :-
   append(R1, R2, L),
   length(L, N),
   N1 is N/2,
   length(R1, N1),
   length(R2, N1).
```

Assume `N` is the length of the list that I will enter manually.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Do you want one result with pairs, all sorted as your example shows, or are you wanting all possible combinations of pairings as your code appears to be trying to do?

Comment: @mbratch Sorry, there was a typo. If I enter [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], I want the output to be [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]. My predicate outputs   [ [[1,2], [3,4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]] ] instead.

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems too much simple, I'm fairly sure I didn't understand your requirement. Anyway, you could try

```
pairs([X,Y],[[X,Y]]).
pairs([X,Y|R],[[X,Y]|T]) :- pairs(R, T).
```

Answer (score 3):

```
group([], []).
group([A, B | Tail], [[A, B] | NewTail]) :-
    group(Tail, NewTail).
```

Test run:

```
?- group([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], X).
X = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]].

?- group([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], X).
false.

?- group([], X).
X = [].
```